# Как установить domain для куков с поддомена?

Tags: express

Почему express-session устанавливает всегда domain тот с которого они куки были установлены а не тот domain - который указан.

Например я с поддомена хочу установить domain =  .site.com

Но у меня не выходит, он как ставил domain subdomain.site.com - так и ставит

```
    app.use(
  expressSession({
    saveUninitialized: true,
    secret: process.env.SESSION_KEY,
    resave: true,
    cookie: {
      sameSite: "none",
      secure: true,
    },
  })
);
 
 // пример установки куков
  res.cookie("accessToken", tokens.accessToken, { httpOnly: true, maxAge: 2592000000 })
  res.cookie("refreshToken", tokens.refreshToken, { httpOnly: true, maxAge: 2592000000 });
```